# What init files are sourced in ash for non-interactive, non-login shells?

Tags: linux, bash, dockerfile, ash

I have a Docker container, which uses `alpine:3.7` as base image, and as a result, uses `/bin/ash` as its shell.

I put the container into background running mode. My intend is that I can continually use `docker exec $CONTAINER_ID <command>` at it. Thus, the command would be executed in non-interactive, non-login shell mode.

But, sometimes my `<command>` is in a non-standard path, therefore I would like to `export PATH` so I don't type fully qualified paths. Or, sometimes some software installation requires me to put some commands in our shell init files (e.g. `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`).

The problem is: under `/bin/ash` shell, for a non-interactive, non-login shell command execution, where can I export this new `PATH`, or my `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`, so that I can do my `docker exec` with everything loaded/sourced appropriately?

I would also consider Bash if Ash cannot do it.

Comment: Can't you update `PATH` from the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @chepner That's right. Totally correct. Sorry, however I also have a command I need to source in all shells (e.g. `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in [pyenv installation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout)) in order for my `pyenv` to work properly.

Comment: Absolutely no files whatsoever are sourced unless the `ENV` environment variable is set containing such a filename. Generally speaking, it's the responsibility of the parent process to set an appropriate environment variable.

Comment: Why don't you execute `/usr/bin/env PATH=/whatever/you/want /bin/ash`? Or just set an appropriate directive in your Dockerfile to have Docker export the desired path before the shell is started in the first place? (See https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For `PATH` it can work like you said, but for sourcing commands like `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` I can't see how it can work...

Comment: @StephenChu, agreed, but I don't see *why* you need to run such a command. It sets a set of environment variables, yes? Their values don't change between runs, yes? Though you certainly *could* write a script that does something like `set -a; eval "$(pyenv init -)"; exec "$@"`, save it as `with-pyenv`, and then run `with-pyenv /bin/ash ...whatever...`

Answer (score 3):

The file named by the environment variable `ENV` is sourced when a POSIX-compliant shell (or bash in POSIX mode) is started in interactive mode, or when 1999 BSD ash is started under any conditions. If you want to support bash when in non-POSIX mode as well, you'll also want to set `BASH_ENV` (which, like legacy BSD ash, is honored even for noninteractive shells).

*Some versions of ash* (including modern dash and busybox ash) *follow the POSIX sh standard on this point*, and consequently only honor ENV when invoked in interactive mode.

This means that with images following the 1999 BSD documentation for ash behavior, you can tell Docker to update the environment variable `ENV` to point to a file which, when sourced by a shell interpreter, will run `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`.

For images with newer or more-compliant versions of ash, consider using bash instead, and setting `BASH_ENV`.